# 2d ArrayList and pulling the second element in a specific index

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know if what I am trying to accomplish is even doable. I have created a 2d arrayList (it could be a list in a list), and I need to pull the second element in the list, and then add it together.

Hopefully, I have all the code that is needed for help. I am so new at this and this is the last part of my assignment that I just can't figure out.

```
//member variable/arrays
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> courseGrade = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> courseGradeTotal = new ArrayList<>();
    private int countCourseEnrollment = 0;
    private int takeCode;
    private static int totalGrade1 = 0;
    private static int grade1 = 0

//method to calculate course average
public static void calculateOverallGrade() {
        Course.listCourses();

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("Enter the course code to get course average:");
        String takeCode1 = Main.scan.next();

        System.out.println("Current students in course: " + takeCode1);


        for (ArrayList<Object> currentStudent : courseEnrollment) {
            if (currentStudent.contains(takeCode1)) {
                System.out.println(currentStudent);
                int index = currentStudent.indexOf(takeCode1);
                System.out.println(index);
                for (ArrayList<Integer> currentGrade : courseGrade) {
                    int intGrade1 = currentGrade.get(index).get(1);
                    System.out.println(intGrade1);
                    grade1 = grade1 + intGrade1;
                }
                for (ArrayList<Integer> overAll : courseGradeTotal) {
                    int totGrade1 = overAll.get(index).get(1);
                    System.out.print(totGrade1);
                    totalGrade1 = totalGrade1 + totGrade1;
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println("Student grades: " + grade1);
        System.out.println("Total grades could have earned: " + totalGrade1);



    } //ends CalculateOverAllGrade method
```

In this method the second .get has an error of Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Integer'. The output from Array courseGrade is [4643, 98]. First number is the course code and the second number is the grade awarded to student. I hope this all makes sense, thank you in advance for your help.

I have tried so many things I just don't know where to start.

Comment: What is `courseEnrollment` ?  I don't see where that is defined. You should be getting  compiler error on `for (ArrayList<Object> currentStudent : courseEnrollment)` as well as the `.get`

Comment: the courseEnrollment is an ArrayList in the class CourseManagement

Comment: An `ArrayList<Integer>` or an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`? Either way, there should be a line in the code that shows it.

Comment: In your enhanced `for` loops, `overAll` and `currentGrade` are each a "1D" `List<Integer>`.  An invocation of `get` on either one will return *one* `Integer`.  And, and `Integer` doesn't have a `get (int index)` method.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Off-topic: I, and others, don't like parallel arrays or parallel collections. Whatever this is a part of, I wonder if the design could be improved. Putting that aside, you might improve the question by adding more information about what the data in the `List<List<Integer>>`   Objects represent. We can infer some, but we shouldn't  have to.

Comment: I have to agree, I don't like that type of array at all, it just didn't work with what I was trying to do and it ended up being very confusing. I ended up just handing in my assignment and took the loss.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I don't know if what I am trying to accomplish is even doable. I have created a 2d arrayList (it could be a list in a list), and I need to pull the second element in the list, and then add it together. ..."*

Yes, this can be accomplished in *Java*.

> *"... In this method the second .get has an error of Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Integer'. ..."*

You've acquired the *index*, so there is no need to iterate on *courseGrade* or *courseGradeTotal*.

Instead, iterate on the *index* from *courseGrade* and *courseGradeTotal*.

```java
Iterator<Integer> i;
int index;
for (List<?> currentStudent : courseEnrollment)
    if ((index = currentStudent.indexOf(takeCode1)) != -1) {
        i = courseGrade.get(index).iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) grade1 += i.next();
        i = courseGradeTotal.get(index).iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) totalGrade1 += i.next();
    }
```